# How to determine the cost of index creation?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, index

I have a table that I want to create an index on to improve the performance of a couple of `SELECT` queries that use the table.

How can I test whether the index has had any significant detrimental impact on DUI operations on the table?

The table is a log table, so it is written to frequently. Is it a case of running a particular `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query against that table before and after creating the desired index?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a non-production environment, you could simulate your insert / update workload by running [SQL Query Stress](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlQueryStress).  Do that before adding the index to get a baseline, and then after to see how much slower it is, and whether that change is acceptable.

In addition to additional overhead for your DUI operations, another consideration is *blocking*.  You might have different blocking patterns than you're used to, since some `SELECT` queries will be using the new index, and inserts / updates will have to take locks on that index *and* the clustered index.

I only point this out to make the point that DUI "overhead" is not the only consideration.  Adding indexes can often *help* with blocking, since SELECT queries on the narrower NC index won't be blocked by updates to other columns in the clustered index.

---

Without knowing anything about your table, here's a quick walkthrough of what the SQL Query Stress approach might look like.  I'll set up a "LogTable" in a new database:

```
USE [master];
GO

CREATE DATABASE [232113];
GO

ALTER DATABASE [232113] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT;
GO

USE [232113];
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.LogTable
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Col1 DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Col2 CHAR(4) NOT NULL
);
```

Then I use these two queries to simulate the INSERT / UPDATE workload:

```
-- insert a row
INSERT INTO dbo.LogTable
    (Col1, Col2)
VALUES
    (GETDATE(), 'val2');

-- update a random row
UPDATE dbo.LogTable
SET Col2 = 'val3'
WHERE Id = (SELECT TOP (1) Id 
            FROM dbo.LogTable 
            ORDER BY NEWID());
```

Then I run SQL Query Stress over 6 threads, 250 iterations per thread, with a 100 ms delay between each execution.  This completes in about 25 seconds with just the clustered index in place.

[image: screenshot of SQL Query Stress results]

Now I'll create a nonclustered index on Col2, which is affected by both the inserts and the updates:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Col2 ON dbo.LogTable (Col2);
```

Running the test again, it took basically the same amount of time (25 seconds).  Notice that the logical reads went up, so there is some *cost* here (it just didn't affect the overall duration).

[image: screenshot of SQL Query Stress results]

Of course, this is a very simple case, with no other activity on the "server" (my laptop), so the difference is minimal.  But hopefully it demonstrates the concept.